# add dollar sign characters to React app env file

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I need to store variable with $ sign in `env` but when I`m trying to use it gets omitted.

Why is that happens and how to fix it?

```
REACT_APP_EXAMPLE="QWE$EWQ"
```

my log out next:

`QWE`

Comment: did you try with a backslash? like this: "QWE\$EWQ"

Comment: It works, I tried escaping in another way it didn't work well. but with backslash works fine thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to "skip" (escape) the dollar sign.
With the variable name, it serves as a placeholder for the variable value that will added to the string later.

Skip it by using a backslash "\", like this: "QWE\$EWQ".

Answer (score 6):

I had this environment variable:

```
REACT_APP_EXAMPLE="QWE$EWQ"
```

I had to switch to **single quotes** and use a **backslash** to escape `$` properly:

```
REACT_APP_EXAMPLE='QWE\$EWQ'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just I want to add that you should always restart your save after saving ur `.env` file so the new changes would be taken and remember always to prefix the name the react env var with `REACT_APP_` ex:

```
REACT_APP_PASSWORD=Mp\$2626
```